Python selenium and firefox: SessionNotCreatedException
i try to create an automation for firefox and un ahve issue.
when i run this:
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
import time
options=webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"
service = Service(executable_path="C:\\python_projets\\forge\\forge_env\\Scripts\\geckodriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
time.sleep(2)
driver.get("https://duckduckgo.com")
time.sleep(2)

i see a firefox window with the robot beside my adress bar, but the widow close immediatly and i have this error

Exception has occurred: SessionNotCreatedException
Message: Error: NS_BINDING_ABORTED
Stacktrace:
#checkLoadingState@chrome://remote/content/shared/Navigate.sys.mjs:246:28
onStateChange@chrome://remote/content/shared/Navigate.sys.mjs:295:28
File "C:\python_projets\forge\test_selenium.py", line 76, in 
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Error: NS_BINDING_ABORTED
Stacktrace:
#checkLoadingState@chrome://remote/content/shared/Navigate.sys.mjs:246:28
onStateChange@chrome://remote/content/shared/Navigate.sys.mjs:295:28

i use:

firefox: 115 ESR (32bits)
python: 3.12
Selenium package 4.25
Geckodriver 0.35 32 bits

What i expected: to be able to use selenium for automation !
I try to:

use the gockodriver 0.35 64 bit --> error
Use a more easy code:

from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://selenium.dev/')
browser.quit()


this the error:

Problem reading geckodriver versions: error sending request for url (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/trunk/common/geckodriver/geckodriver-support.json). Using
latest geckodriver version
Exception managing firefox: error sending request for url (https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest)
Error sending stats to Plausible: error sending request for url (https://plausible.io/api/event)

